# How do I apply a function to foldr?

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree, fold

This is a relatively simple haskell question but I am having alot of trouble with. 
I'm trying to apply this function 'add' to convert a list of strings into a BST. (The add function simply inserts a term) My questions is how to define the fold so that it applies the add function to the [String] so that it essentially inserts each function one by one?

My initial thought was that the function i'll be applying to xs would be (add _ basetree) where _ would be each element of xs and base tree would be the tree with one element, x. Then foldr would just apply that function to each element of xs. I'm not sure what is wrong, but this is giving me an error.

```
*** Expression     : foldr1 (add x (add x Empty)) xs
*** Term           : add x (add x Empty)
*** Type           : BST
*** Does not match : [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
```

```
data BST = MakeNode BST String BST
           | Empty

add :: String -> BST -> BST

listToTree :: [String] -> BST
listToTree (x:xs) = foldr (add x (add x Empty)) xs -- Here***
```

If someone can help me out that'll be great. I spent like almost 3 hours trying to figure out this foldr already ..

Comment: The biggest issue is that you are using manual recursion by pattern matching and `foldr` at the same time.  The usual usage of `foldr` is to replace manual recursion, not supplement it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by pattern matching and foldr at the same time. I had been reading alot on the syntax for foldr and to my understanding at least, that is the simplest way to use that foldr function ... or am I misunderstanding something? (foldr functiontoapply list)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Gabriel says in a comment, you are combining manual recursion (the pattern match `(x:xs)`) with `foldr` in quite an unusual way. Usually you want to use *either* manual recursion, or you use `foldr` in cases where the recursion follows the pattern "repeatedly apply a function to the elements of a list until you've exhausted the list".

I assume your `add` function looks something like this:

```
add :: String -> BST -> BST
add string Empty            = MakeNode Empty string Empty
add string (MakeNode l s r) =
    if string < s
        then MakeNode (add string l) s r
        else MakeNode l s (add string r)
```

With this out of the way, the function `listToTree` would normally be written in one of two ways. The first is using pattern matching and recursion:

```
listToTree []     = Empty
listToTree (x:xs) = add x (listToTree xs)
```

That is, either you have an empty list, in which case you return the empty tree, or you have a head followed by a tail, in which case you add the head of the list to the tree returned by the tail of the list.

The other approach is to write `listToTree` by folding over the list. This abstracts out the recursion for you, so that you can just write

```
listToTree = foldr add Empty
```

This works because `foldr` has the type

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

and `add` and `Empty` have the types

```
add   :: String -> BST -> BST
Empty :: BST
```

specialising the types `a` and `b`, you get

```
foldr :: (String -> BST -> BST) -> BST -> [String] -> BST
```

which means that

```
foldr add Empty :: [String] -> BST
```

Which of these should you prefer? Perhaps the first one is easier for a beginner to read and understand. However, as you gain more experience with Haskell you will find the second version becomes easier to understand. It's also more concise, and the fact that it's written in terms of a fold allows list fusion rules to be triggered more frequently, which may result in more efficient code.

### Understanding foldr

The key to understanding folds, in my opinion, is to realize that a fold replaces list constructors with whatever functions and constants you give it. In Haskell there are two possible constructors for a list:

```
[]  :: [a]
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

When you desugar all the syntax, lists actually look like this (this is valid Haskell - try it out!)

```
xs = 1 : 2 : 3 : []
```

When you call `foldr op x0 xs`, the fold effectively replaces all of the `(:)` constructors in `xs` with `op`, and all of the `[]` constructors with `x0`:

```
foldr op x0 xs = 1 `op` 2 `op` 3 `op` x0
```

Of course, there's an ambiguity here, because we don't know whether `op` associates to the left or to the right. In order for the types to work out, you must provide a function that associates to the right (that's why it's called a *right* fold), like this:

```
foldr op x0 xs = 1 `op` (2 `op (3 `op` x0))
```

A left fold is the same, except that it associates to the left instead (and puts the initial value at the start of the list rather than the end) so you end up with

```
foldl op x0 xs = ((x0 `op` 1) `op` 2) `op` 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand how to do the recursion way, and I was just trying to do this problem using the fold function. Just wondering, if I wanted to use the add function on the list in a reverse order (ie. left to right), how would I do that? To my understanding, foldr add Empty currently takes the last item of the list and moves towards the first.

Comment: @xLCaliburn: You can use `foldl` (or even better: `Data.List.foldl'`) instead, but it has a slightly different signature, so you need something like `foldl (flip add) Empty`

Comment: perfect. thank you Niklas and Chris again for your answers. If I could upvote you guys I would xD (Upon further analysis, the triple add didn't give me the right tree...)

Answer (score 2):

The type of foldr is

```
(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b,
```

i.e. it takes a function that takes a b, and a list of [a]'s, and returns a b.
Now add here is

```
(String -> BST -> BST),
```

so it becomes

```
(String -> BST -> BST) -> BST -> [String] -> BST,
```

now, I can't compile it, as I don't have the add function, but I believe

```
listToTree (x:xs) = foldr add (add x (add x Empty)) xs
```

will do the trick. It's type signature is the same at least.
Now this should add the start of the list twice, but maybe your Add function ignores duplicates? It would better if you could include it, so that we might investigate it further.

Comment: Yours was better. I think it is more in line with what he was is trying to do, I was just making a function that approximated the type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After testing this and making a small change, this was actually exactly what I was looking for.
One small change:
listToTree (x:xs) = foldr add (add x (add x Empty)) xs

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the arguments to listToTree. Anyway, happy haskelling!

Comment: @xLCaliburn Do you mean to add the first string to the tree twice? That's what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: I need to spend some time to figure out why this works the way it does. At the moment it works the way I would like it to:

`BinarySearchTree> listToTree ["Joe","Bob"] `
returns: 
`"Joe"
    "Bob"`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want:

```
listToTree = foldr add Empty
```

`foldr` has type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> a`

so it takes and accumulator function and an initial value. `Empty` is your initial tree value, and `add` constructs a new tree given an element and the existing tree.